# Use of the Student T distribution for the t-statistic

Tags: t-test, t-distribution

The variable $T$ is given by the classic form of the one-sample t-test the population mean under a hypothesis such as $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$

$$T = \frac{\bar{X_n}-\mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}$$

where $\bar{X_n} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)}$ and where $X_i$ follows some distribution with population mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2<\infty$. I am aware of the following two cases:

(1) If $X_i \sim^{i.i.d} N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for $i=1,..,.n$ then $T$ is (exactly) Student T distributed with $n-1$ degrees of freedom

(2) If $X_i$ is drawn $i.i.d$ for all $i=1,...,n$ from a distribution with a finite second moment, then $T$ converges to a standard normal distribution as $n\rightarrow \infty$ (see a great derivation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97268/is-there-a-theorem-that-says-that-sqrtn-frac-barx-mus-converges-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Now, in practical, large-sample applications of the one-sample t-test, I understand that $T$ is only normally distributed in the limit. Thus, it is usually stated that one should use a Student T distribution for $T$ when determining critical-values, etc (for instance, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/t-test-for-non-normal-when-n50?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428917/t-test-for-a-non-normal-population?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85804/choosing-between-z-test-and-t-test?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I understand that a Student T distribution also converges to a Normal distribution as $n\rightarrow \infty$, but this is not sufficient justification to use the Student T distribution for the random variable $T$ for finite (even if large) $n$.

All answers to this question that I have seen argue that using the Student T distribution is more conservative: either this is just stated with intuitive appeal to the fact that we have to estimate $\sigma$ using $S$ (which is not nearly enough in my mind to justify the use of the Student T distribution) or appeals to simulation (again, not enough since these simulations can only ever test a finite number of distributions for $X_i$). For instance, this is approximately the answer given for this extremely well written question on the exact same topic [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590023/why-is-t-test-more-appropriate-than-z-test-for-non-normal-data).

To this end, I am looking for some sort of mathematical (not intuitive and not based on simulation) justification that $T$ not only can but should be approximated as a Student T distribution in the case where $X_i$ are not normally distributed, $\sigma$ is unknown, and $n$ is finite (but large). A reference to a textbook or journal article would also be sufficient.

Comment: I doubt any such reference exists unless it closely circumscribes the possible parent distributions.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411699 for an extremely well-known and practical counterexample.

Comment: I guess I'm confused mathematically of where the use of the Student T distribution comes from? We either have only that the asymptotic distribution is Normal or the exact distribution is Student T if $X_i$ are iid Normal. So where does the Student T come into play from a mathematical perspective for finite (but large) $n$? I don't see the mathematical justification.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong direction: the innovation of Student's *t* test lies in its application to *small* $n,$ not large $n.$  The *mathematical* justification arises from a Normality assumption about the parent distribution.  The *statistical* justification requires pointing to practical situations where that Normality assumption is reasonable.  That's what "Student" did in his original 1908 paper, where he examined subsamples of size 4 from a morphometric dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the response @whuber. I think my confusion comes with the general advice (e.g., see the answer to this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430758/under-what-conditions-should-i-use-an-approximate-z-score-vs-a-t-test?noredirect=1&lq=1) that we always resort to using the Student T distribution if the variance is unknown. I understand that simple rules of thumb for applying the CLT (e.g., $n>=30$) can be problematic based on the underlying distribution of the data. -----

Comment: However, the proposal that one should then use a t-test instead of a z-test seems misguided. If $n=30$, let's say, is not enough to appeal to the CLT in a particular case, then how is the use of the Student T a solution to the problem if your data is not Normal? If $n=30$ is enough, then just use the Normal; if $n=30$ is not enough, what justification is there for using the Student T when the underlying data is not Normal?

Comment: There's a good reason the answer you reference has no upvotes!  The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69898 provides some counterpoint to it (and, I believe, support for your position).  However, see the duplicate threads for some rationale for using the t test regardless, especially https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85811/919.